# I need help Highchart Xaxis multiple label

Tags: javascript, jquery

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ERhGU.jpg)

Is it possible that the high chart in image? red square box label. 
I can not find the function...

1line label day night,
2line label date(merge)

2016-08-16 day/2016-08-16 night ||| 2016-08-17 day/2016-08-17 night

```
      2016-08-16                        2016-08-17
```

javascript source

```
$(function () {
    $('#container').highcharts({

        chart: {
            type: 'column'
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Total fruit consumtion, grouped by gender'
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['DAY', 'NIGHT', 'DAY', 'NIGHT']
        },

        yAxis: {
            allowDecimals: false,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Number of fruits'
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            formatter: function () {
                return '<b>' + this.x + '</b><br/>' +
                    this.series.name + ': ' + this.y + '<br/>' +
                    'Total: ' + this.point.stackTotal;
            }
        },

        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5],
            stack: 'male'
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, 5, 6, 2, 1],
            stack: 'female'
        }, {
            name: 'Janet',
            data: [3, 0, 4, 4, 3],
            stack: 'female'
        }]
    });
});
```

Additional x -axis underneath want to add a date to .

Comment: Tried to do something like this once. As far as I know, there is no built-in way to do this. There is a plugin that does something along those lines: http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/11/Grouped-Categories

Answer (score 0):

add `<br>` in category will make the axis having multiple rows. Extra row looks like a grouped title.

```
    xAxis: {
        type: 'category',
        categories: ['Jan<br>一月<br>Q1', 'Feb<br>二月', 'Mar<br>三月', 
                     'Apr<br>四月<br>Q2', 'May<br>五月', 'Jun<br>六月',
                     'Jul<br>七月<br>Q3', 'Aug<br>八月', 'Sep<br>九月', 
                     'Oct<br>十月<br>Q4', 'Nov<br>十一月', 'Dec<br>十二月']
    },
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rockiey/t5xuo9do/